# How to let the input in react accepts only float number between 0 and 1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have a text input that I want it to accept only float numbers between 0 and 1.

```
const Page = () => {

//previous states ...
const [currentElectricityPrice, setCurrentElectricityPrice] = useState(0.0);

 const onCurrentElectricityPriceChange = (
    event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const { value } = event.currentTarget;
    if (validateFloat(value)) setCurrentElectricityPrice(parseFloat(value));
  };
return (

<>
...
         <TextField
                ID=""
                placeholder=""
                value={currentElectricityPrice}
                onChange={onCurrentElectricityPriceChange}
                outline
                unit="€/kWh"
                step={0.01}
              />
}
```

float validation regex:

```
export const validateFloat = (value: string) => {
  const pattern = /^(0(\.\d+)?|1(\.0+)?)$/;
  return pattern.test(value);
};
```

The problem with this it allows only 0 ( the original state ).

My constraints are:

1. 000.00 (wrong )
2. 111 (wrong)
3. 0.1111 ( okay )
4. 1  ( okay )
5. 1.0 ( wrong)

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-rui-cxrlhz?file=/src/App.js)

THANK YOU.

Comment: Between 0 and 1, or between *and including* 0 and 1? Also, are you saying you want to accept `1` but not `1.0`? Does this also mean you want to accept `0` but not `000.00`?

Comment: Between 0 and 1 and including 0 and 1. Yeas, I want to avoid leasing 0 such as : 0000 or 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of preventing user from inputting, which can be considered bad UX, you can validate `value` with [`.setCustomValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setCustomValidity) and [`.reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/reportValidity) on `<input type="number">`:

```js
const handler = (event) => {
  const inputElement = event.target
  const value = Number(inputElement.value);
  const isValid = 0 <= value && value <= 1;

  if (!isValid) {
    inputElement.setCustomValidity('Input must be in range [0, 1]')
    inputElement.reportValidity();
  } else {
    inputElement.setCustomValidity('');
  }
};
```

`<input type="number">` saves you the need of filtering out non-numeric input, even though it may accepts more than you expect (for example, `1e3` is valid). That's where `.setCustomValidity()`/`.reportValidity()` comes in: It displays a nice, browser-based notice to let the user know that their input is invalid.

Note the `<input>`'s [`step="any"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step); it allows decimal numbers of arbitrary precision.

Try it:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

function App() {
  const handler = (event) => {
    const inputElement = event.target
    const value = Number(inputElement.value);
    const isValid = 0 <= value && value <= 1;

    if (!isValid) {
      console.log({ value, isValid });
      inputElement.setCustomValidity('Input must be in range [0, 1]')
      inputElement.reportValidity();
    } else {
      inputElement.setCustomValidity('');
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" step="any" onInput={handler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have a resource on UX/UI that talks about the bad practice of preventing users from inputting?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin If I were your user I would be leaving your site after 5 seconds. On a more realistic hand, see [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/30643) on our sister site.

Comment: Yes, but I made the requirements for each field.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin I'm afraid I don't understand. Which requirements? How are those relevant to my advice of not changing the field on input?

Comment: For example in the percent field I make the placeholder: `Max: 100` and prevent the user from passing this value, instead of letting them pass this value, what do you think?

Should I display an error message ( like you did ) when the user enter the value?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin If you are asking it as a generic question, that is out of scope for my answer. Ask a new question on [ux.se] or [codereview.se].